# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf2docsx'

Tags: python

I have tried to write a sample code that converts the contents of pdf to word
this is the code :

```
from pdf2docsx import converter

pdf = 'main.pdf'
word = 'my.docx'
cv = converter(pdf)

cv.convert(word,start=0,end=None)
cv.close()
```

Although i already installed the module pdf2docx , it still doesn't exist

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dell\Desktop\New folder (8)\My_Start\python\PdfToWord.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pdf2docsx import converter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdf2docsx'
```

[image]

Comment: There is a typo in the import. It should be `pdf2docx` without the `s`.

Comment: It's telling you the truth.

Comment: Please check the [documentation](https://dothinking.github.io/pdf2docx/quickstart.convert.html). The `C` is capitalized in `Converter`. So, it should be `from pdf2docx import Converter`.

Answer (score 0):

The module appears to be called pdf2docx, whereas you have added an "s" to make pdf2docsx

https://pypi.org/project/pdf2docx/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `import` to

```
from pdf2docx import converter
```

There's not supposed to be an "s" there